# Сглаживание линий в Canvas

Tags: canvas, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Нашёл такой слайдер, где реализован прогресс-баг: http://www.soslignes-ecrivain-public.fr/DEMO-Progress-Bar-Nivo-Slider.html
Но линии круга, как видно, нечеткие. Как их разгладить? Есть как пример нечто похожее: http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/ (правый верхний угол). Надо, как тут.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить.

Answer (score 2):

Тут дело не в JS или Canvas, картинка bullets-NDS30.png, которая используется в слайдере, сама по себе такая. Если хотите четкие линии круга, то стоит править ее.